# What number of confirmations is considered secure in Cardano?

Tags: decentralized-applications, security

There is `k` finalization param in Ouroboros, but it is absolutely non-practical. It takes around 36 hours AFAIU.

Comment: Related questions: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8760/what-is-your-comfort-level-for-number-of-confirmations-and-why

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the amount of ADA at risk.

Personally I would be happy with 3 block confirmations for a value of US $10, but would want more than that for US $10,000.

Rollbacks of more than 3 blocks are roughly once a year events.

Comment: Agree, DbSync waits two blocks before inserting in database, just for reference

Comment: > Rollbacks of more than 3 blocks are roughly once a year events.


Are there any stats available on rollbacks?